# Countifs in Macros

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm trying to update an old macro that needs to validate two conditions, rather than one.

Here is the current code:

```
Columns("G:G").Select
TempString = "IF(RC[4]>0,""1,"","""")&IF(RC[7]>0,""2,"","""")&IF(RC[10]>0,""3,"","""")&IF(RC[13]>0,""4,"","""")"
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(" + TempString + ") > 0, LEFT( " + TempString + ", LEN( " + TempString + " ) - 1 ), " + TempString + " )"
Columns("G:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("G1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Map"
```

Here is the code I'm trying to use. I want it to validate two conditions, rather than the current one now. It should validate the column name, as well as the cell that's four immediate spaces to the right (If there's a number greater than 0 in the cell, it's true):

```
Columns("G:G").Select
TempString = "IF(COUNTIFS(R[-1]C[4],"*MAP*", RC[4], ">0"),""1,"","""")&IF(COUNTIFS(R[-1]C[7],"*MAP*", RC[7], ">0"),""1,"","""")"
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(" + TempString + ") > 0, LEFT( " + TempString + ", LEN( " + TempString + " ) - 1 ), " + TempString + " )"
Columns("G:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("G1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Map"
```

When I try to use the updated code, I get "Expected: End of Statement." I understand it's because of the commas, but I don't know to pull it in to a macro. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try adding additional double quotes around *MAP*

Comment: ...and the `">0"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```vba
TempString = "IF(COUNTIFS(R[-1]C[4],""*MAP*"", RC[4], "">0""),""1,"","""")&" & _
              "IF(COUNTIFS(R[-1]C[7],""*MAP*"", RC[7], "">0""),""1,"","""")"

With Columns("G:G")
    .FormulaR1C1 = Replace("=IF(LEN(<ts>)>0, LEFT(<ts>, LEN(<ts>)-1),<ts>)", _
                           "<ts>", TempString)
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
Range("G1").Value = "Map"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. No errors pop up, but I am getting a #REF! in the cell, specifically on the first portion of the formula. In the cell, it displays "=IF(LEN(IF(COUNTIFS(#REF!,"*MAP*", RC[4], ">0"),"1,","")&IF(COUNTIFS(#REF!,"*MAP*", RC[7], ">0"),"1,","")) > 0, LEFT( IF(COUNTIFS(#REF!,"*MAP*", RC[4], ">0"),"1,","")&IF(COUNTIFS(#REF!,"*MAP*", RC[7], ">0"),"1,",""), LEN( IF(COUNTIFS(#REF!,"*MAP*", RC[4], ">0"),"1,","")&IF(COUNTIFS(#REF!,"*MAP*", RC[7], ">0"),"1,","") ) - 1 ), IF(COUNTIFS(#REF!,"*MAP*", RC[4], ">0"),"1,","")&IF(COUNTIFS(#REF!,"*MAP*", RC[7], ">0"),"1,","") )